# Why my Node.js ServerResponse **wrapped by Proxy** doesn't respond?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next

This must be a very specific and weird question.

This works obviously,

```js
import http from 'http';

http.createServer(function(_req, res) {
  res.end('yeah!');
}).listen(3000);
```

But this doesn't. The server doesn't respond to a request.

```js
import http from 'http';

http.createServer(function(_req, res) {
  const pres = new Proxy(res, {});
  pres.end('yeah!');
}).listen(3000);
```

I need to wrap ServerResponse for some reason... I'm debugging but no clue. **What such a proxied object can differ from an original object?** Symbols? Property definitions? If anyone knows about this, please, please post. Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure that out. The function context (`this`) should be the original ServerResponse itself.

```js
import http from 'http';

http.createServer(function(_req, res) {
  const pres = new Proxy(res, {
    get(t, p, r) {
      const v = Reflect.get(t, p, r);
      if (typeof v === 'function') return v.bind(t);
      return v;
    },
  });
  pres.end('yeah!');
}).listen(3000);
```

Da.